# Unable to extract the octet from an ip address properly in shell script

Tags: shell-script

`ipfile.txt` is formatted in the following way:

```
ServerA 127.0.0.1
ServerB 192.168.1.254
ServerC 4.2.2.1
```

Desired Output of shell script:

```
ServerA   Class A
ServerB   Class C
ServerC   Class A
```

I couldn't figure out a better way to extract only the first octet. My script so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Take input IP from file and classify according to classful addressing. 

while read ip;do
        octet=$(awk -F'[ .]' '{print $2}' ipfile.txt)
        if [[ "$octet" -ge 1 && "$octet" -le 127 ]];then
                echo "ServerA Class A"
        fi
        if [[ "$octet" -ge 128 && "$octet" -le 191 ]];then
                echo "ServerB Class B"
        fi
        if [[ "$octet" -ge 192 && "$octet" -le 223 ]];then
                echo "ServerC Class C"
        fi
done < ipfile.txt
```

I am getting syntax errors:

```
./ipclassgen.sh: line 7: [[: 127
192
4: syntax error in expression (error token is "192
4")
./ipclassgen.sh: line 10: [[: 127
192
4: syntax error in expression (error token is "192
4")
./ipclassgen.sh: line 13: [[: 127
192
4: syntax error in expression (error token is "192
4")
./ipclassgen.sh: line 7: [[: 127
192
4: syntax error in expression (error token is "192
4")
./ipclassgen.sh: line 10: [[: 127
192
4: syntax error in expression (error token is "192
4")
./ipclassgen.sh: line 13: [[: 127
192
4: syntax error in expression (error token is "192
4")
./ipclassgen.sh: line 7: [[: 127
192
4: syntax error in expression (error token is "192
4")
./ipclassgen.sh: line 10: [[: 127
192
4: syntax error in expression (error token is "192
4")
./ipclassgen.sh: line 13: [[: 127
192
4: syntax error in expression (error token is "192
4")
./ipclassgen.sh: line 7: [[: 127
192
4: syntax error in expression (error token is "192
4")
./ipclassgen.sh: line 10: [[: 127
192
4: syntax error in expression (error token is "192
4")
./ipclassgen.sh: line 13: [[: 127
192
4: syntax error in expression (error token is "192
4")
```

How can I do this without using awk and specifying the file. I am not sure where the syntax errors are either.

Comment: IP address classes were replaced by [Classless Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) in *1993*. That's nearly three decades ago! Address classes are dead, and it doesn't make any sense to keep categorizing addresses by this obsolete system. (Well, except for classes D and E, but that's not what we're talking about here.)

Comment: ^ What they said, a hundred times more. If you're reading for a Cisco exam you're excused, but please just promise to not talk about address classes to anyone after that... (As an aside, `0/8` is in Class A. I mean **WAS**.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read the file linewise into the `ip` variable, but never use it. Then you assign the second field of ALL lines to the `octet` variable, separated by `<NL>` (\n, 0x0A), reading the file AGAIN. `bash` then stumbles over the multiple lines in `octet` when doing the test.
Try instead:

```
while read server ip
  do    octet=${ip%%.*}
.
.
.
  done < file
```

Please note also that it might be smarter not to hard code the server names but use the `server` variable read from the file:

```
if [[ "$octet" -ge 1 && "$octet" -le 127 ]]
  then  echo "$server: Class A"
  fi
```

P.S.: You could even have `read` split the line for you:

```
while IFS=" ." read server ip1 ip2 ip3 ip4
  do if [[ "$ip1" ...
```

Comment: How does this `octet=${ip%%.*}` work? Is this string formatting?

Comment: That is `bash`'s "Parameter Expansion: Remove matching suffix pattern" (cf. `man bash`).

Comment: Do we need four ip variables if we are extracting and comparing only the first octet?

Comment: No. They are for your convenience, should the need for them arise some point in time. You can read the last three into a dummy variable to be discarded.